# How to take dependencies into account when running tests?

Tags: c++, c, testing, makefile, cmake

I would like to know how to take dependencies into account when running tests. For example, if I have a non-regression test, say check.exe, generated from a file check.c/check.cpp (containing a main function) which depends on a header file foo.h, how to run this test only when foo.h, or foo.c, or foo.cpp, or any related file has been modified?

I already know how to rebuild check.exe with CMake whenever some related file has been modified. My question deals with the possibility of running check.exe only when it has been rebuilt.

Comment: Isn't that what make does for you already?

Comment: Use a build system. CMake, SCons, make and lots of others exist to solve this problem for you.

Comment: I already use CMake and it makes the job for compilation and linking steps. But how can I do when it is about running an executable?

Comment: `My question deals with the possibility of running check.exe only when it has been rebuilt.` - The question is pretty clear, *specific* and *answerable*. Voted for reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question deals with the possibility of running check.exe only when it has been rebuilt.

Register running `check.exe` as *POST_BUILD* event of the target:

```
add_executable(check check.c ....)
# This command will be called whenever 'check' is rebuilt.
add_custom_command(TARGET check POST_BUILD COMMAND check)
```